# Unable to Authorize Mail/Printer etc

Tags: 18.04, printing, password, email, authentication

I have this weird problem on my ubuntu 18.04 laptop where I cannot login to my email through any email client (thunderbird/mailspring/hiri etc.) or I can't add a shared online printer (Windows Printer via SAMBA) with password protection. The problem is that it always says that my password is incorrect. However, when I do the same configurations for the same email clients or for the same printer using the same username/password on another machine with ubuntu, everything works perfectly! So, I am sure that the configurations or the credentials are not wrong. There seems to be a setting off/wrong/missing somewhere that is not allowing me to sign in to such 'online' stuff. Been searching for a solution for days, but nothing came up so far.

Thank you kind stranger for reading and helping out, hopefully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with printing, my user was in sudoers but, apparently not in the lpadmin group, so running:

sudo usermod -aG lpadmin user_name

solved the problem. Hope that this helps anyone who also has a similar problem.